# Generate type for partial function

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function with declared type. I plan to use a partial version of this function. But I need to declare the variable first for the partial version.

I can copy the signature, omitting the first parameter.
While it works and do type checks, I would like to automate this.

This is how I want to use it:

```
function myFunc(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b
}

let partFunc: PartialFunc<typeof myFunc>

// later
partFunc = (b) => myFunc(42, b)
```

And I don't know if it's possible to create `PartialFunc<Func>` generic.

I tried this approach

```
interface Func1<T1, TRes> {
    (a: T1): TRes
}
interface Func2<T1, T2, TRes> {
    (a: T1, b: T2): TRes
}
interface PartialFunc<TFunc extends Func2<T1, T2, TRes>, T1=any, T2=any, TRes=any> extends Func1<T2, TRes>{}
```

or the same with generic types:

```
type F1<T1, TRes> = (a: T1) => TRes
type F2<T1, T2, TRes> = (a: T1, b: T2) => TRes
type PF<Func extends F2<T1, T2, TRes>, T1=any, T2=any, TRes=any> = F1<T2, TRes>
```

But this still requires me to specify all the types:

```
let partFunc: PF<typeof myFunc, number, number, number>
```

otherwise I have `any` types.

While this enforces the type check, e.g. it will not accept `PF<typeof myFunc, number, number, string>`, I would like to avoid writing types again.

Basically I want to say to TS *Take the signature of this function and remove first param*

Is there any solution for this?

Context of this task - I have a `react-redux` application, and I want to bind the parameter from store to action dispatcher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TypeScript 2.8 and up you can use [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to do this, by leveraging the awesome [type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) feature.  Here's how you might use it in this particular situation:

```
type RemoveFirstParamFromTwoParamFunction<F extends (a: any, b: any)=>any> =
  F extends (a: any, b: infer B) => infer R ? (b: B) => R : never

function myFunc(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b
}

let partFunc: RemoveFirstParamFromTwoParamFunction<typeof myFunc>;
partFunc = (b) => myFunc(42, b);
```

Notice how this only works on concrete functions of exactly two required parameters.  If you need it to work on possibly-generic functions of more/fewer possibly-optional parameters, you will have to work harder to get it done by enumerating cases and testing thoroughly.  That's because TypeScript currently (as of TypeScript 2.8) lacks [a way to programmatically access function parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453).  The exact type of `RemoveFirstParam<>` you need depends on your use case.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.