# Typescript infer rest type of generic object type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing a partial function for react-alike functional components. It accepts a single parameter `props`, then fill a specific key of the props. For example, the partial function `foo` fills value of prop `bar` to the new component.

```js
function foo<T extends {bar: number}>(functionalComponent: (props: T) => JSX.Element) {
  return (props: Omit<T, 'bar'>) => {
    return functionalComponent({...props, bar: 3});
  }
}
```

However, typescript compiler complains:

> 'Omit<T, "bar"> & { bar: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ bar: number; }'

The problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50437261/5930115), which uses `infer` for a parameter list. However, I didn't find an object version, instead I found [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41157#issuecomment-711462358), which suggests using `Omit`. However, `Omit` does not work for the generic.

A tiny example to illustrate the problem:

```js
function func<T extends {foo: number}>(param: Omit<T, 'foo'>): T {
  return {...param, foo: 3};
}
```

> 'Omit<T, "foo"> & { foo: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ foo: number; }'

I also checked [an answer that explains this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/5930115), but still can't get the point.

How can I make the partial function type signature work?

Comment: is it working if you forget about `Omit` and replace `return (props: T) => {` by `return (props: T) => {`

Comment: @Daniel Did you write a typo? It seems there is no difference :)

Comment: yes, typo. I meant replace line `return (props: Omit<T, 'bar'>) => {` by `return (props: T) => {`

Comment: Sorry this is not a desired behavior, since the wrapped function should have a param signature `Omit<T, 'bar'>` because it partially wraps component so that callers of the returned function doesn't have to provide value of `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript can't follow what will happen with the `Omit` as long as it still has an unresolved generic type parameter in it. What we could do to get this to type check is to add a union with `Omit<T, 'bar'> & {bar: number}` to `props` of `functionalComponent`. While this seems the same as `T`, it's inclusion will let typescript assign the wrapped component props to the functional component props. When `T` is resolved, `T` and `Omit<T, 'bar'> & {bar: number}` will resolve to the same effective type, so it should have no impact to the call site:

```
type BaseProps ={bar: number}
function foo<T extends BaseProps>(functionalComponent: (props: 
    | T 
    | Omit<T, 'bar'> & BaseProps ) => JSX.Element) {
  return (props: Omit<T, 'bar'>) => {
    return functionalComponent({...props, bar: 3});
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQLABQ9MAnmFnAEJpYAKxY6AXgDeAI2RQAXHAB2AVxAisUAL70Cs6fmARpcAhAgAeACpwsADxhZpAE3SdUPPqgB8ACnWaY26cgA2AMIkkNLWMFJuYM5S9HBxcAA+cKax8UkA8iDAMCYANORiUGQucABkHFy8EPxwAJRwAiUAUgDKABoAdACiflggYfVCqZQwslC6kdFwmdl5BeLF9Y1wQ3TxcCNjup5aOv5B4DphbkIdZ1HVqPmFUgDMyrUA3KmqdK9qGru6VqgwkVJCOA3GTyRRQfL6CBSOQKJRwB4rVJxTbjOCGFyGAD0Lno7zovXgAHcoMgwKwbMYsL8GnoDG4fjAnvRiaTyZTfickbSoXAAIy5XG1ZkkslYClUv6rdaQqT8rnA3lwTGYuBdKDEKCCoA)

Answer (score 0):

I found a brute-force workaround: using the `as` keyword. Not sure if there exists a better solution, so I'll leave it unresolved.

```js
function func<T extends {foo: number}>(param: Omit<T, 'foo'>): T {
  return {...param, foo: 3} as T;
}
```